# Best way to setup ELK in production

Tags: elastic-stack

Is it a good practice to setup Elasticsearch, logstash and kiban on 3 different servers, with each server having RAM of 8GB. 
Or 
Setup ELK on 1 single machine with higher memory of 16GB. 
The machine needs to be highly available.
Can anyone suggest or share inputs

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your task and situation. normally it is good practice to setup Elasticsearch, logstash and kiban on 3 different server. or if you data if more so you have to make a cluster of elastic search or may have more than one server of logstash .
filefeats will be on all the data(log) server .
there are an example of handling 25000 logs per secoung
https://engineering.viki.com/blog/2015/log-processing-at-scale-elk-cluster-at-25k-events-per-second/

Answer (score 0):

Its slightly more complicated than explained here,

Any distributed component would try to offer features with sharded or partioned way. In a similar way the Elastic Search at ELK which is based out of Master Slave model and maintains the data at ES data nodes. This means one needs to set up a cluster of nodes for Elastic search itself for its various components such as ES Master, ES data and ES client.

The next level if the system is required at production grade which requires Multi master setup with minimum 3 master nodes.

This would be the beginning of ELK.

If one needs to run such a complex system in a limited resources, then Containerizing the ELK components and running them in a container orchestration framework is the recommended option. Kubernetes/Docker swarm are the options to run ELK cluster based on the dockerized instances of ELK. Again these orchestration frameworks also require multimaster setup , but that would be fair as one would have lot more components in a cloud environment and all of them could be controlled under these orchestration frameworks.